# Animate cell when pressed using Swift 3

Tags: swift, animation, swift3, uicollectionview, cell

My problem is really simple. I would like to animate a cell within a collectionView. Indeed, I would like to show a grey background behind the cell and scale down the image inside.

It would be (almost) the same effect than Pinterest:

[image]

I used to code that animation on buttons, but I never did that on a cell. How can link a cell to a touchUpInside or TouchDown action for example ?

Comment: I would like to lauch the action when I touch Down, and release when Touch up inside

Answer (score 81, accepted):

If you want to start animation when you touch on the cell, you can implement `didHighlightItemAt`. You probably want to reverse it in `didUnhighlightItemAt`:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CustomCell {            
            cell.imageView.transform = .init(scaleX: 0.95, y: 0.95)
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.95, green: 0.95, blue: 0.95, alpha: 1)
        }
    }
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didUnhighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CustomCell {
            cell.imageView.transform = .identity
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
    }
}
```

That yields:

[image: demo]

Comment: doesn't work Autolayout Constraint is used for wrapper view in cell

Comment: This example was done entirely with autolayout constraints. It's why I used `transform` rather than adjusting `frame`, precisely so it wouldn't interfere/conflict with autolayout. If you really want, you can achieve the same thing by adjusting leading, trailing, top, and bottom constraints and animating the call to `layoutIfNeeded()`, but that is unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 9):

If you need implement this functionality only for the specific cell, just add this code to you cell implementation:

```
override var isHighlighted: Bool {
  didSet {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
      let scale: CGFloat = 0.9
      self.transform = self.isHighlighted ? CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale) : .identity
    }
  }
}
```

It is the same answer that suggested [pgdev][1] but for `isHighlighted`

Answer (score 7):

Swift 4.2, inside the UICollectionViewCell

```
    //MARK:- Events
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        animate(isHighlighted: true)
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        animate(isHighlighted: false)
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)
        animate(isHighlighted: false)
    }

    //MARK:- Private functions
    private func animate(isHighlighted: Bool, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?=nil) {
        let animationOptions: UIView.AnimationOptions = [.allowUserInteraction]
        if isHighlighted {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
                           delay: 0,
                           usingSpringWithDamping: 1,
                           initialSpringVelocity: 0,
                           options: animationOptions, animations: {
                            self.transform = .init(scaleX: 0.96, y: 0.96)
            }, completion: completion)
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
                           delay: 0,
                           usingSpringWithDamping: 1,
                           initialSpringVelocity: 0,
                           options: animationOptions, animations: {
                            self.transform = .identity
            }, completion: completion)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

In your custom `UICollectionViewCell`, change the `imageView` `transform` when the cell is selected, i.e

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override var isSelected: Bool{
        didSet{
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0) {
                self.imageView.transform = self.isSelected ? CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9) : CGAffineTransform.identity
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift : 4**  You need to implement custom `UICollectionViewCell`, change the `contentView` OR `imageView` `transform` when the cell is selected

```
override var isSelected: Bool {
                didSet{
                       UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: 
                        {
                             self.contentView.transform = self.isSelected ? CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.95, y: 0.95) : CGAffineTransform.identity
                             self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.95, green: 0.95, blue: 0.95, alpha: 1)
                        }) { (true) in
                        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations:
                        {
                             self.contentView.transform = self.isSelected ?  CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0) : CGAffineTransform.identity
                             self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                        })
                    } 
                 }
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

**You have several options.**

- You can implement the collection view delegate method `collectionView(:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:)` and put your code there.
- You can attach a tap gesture recognizer to your view that you want to respond to taps.
- You Can create a custom button and install an image into it and then use the IBAction method of the button as normal.