# UICollectionViewCell Custom Animation On Tap

Tags: swift, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

My goal is to build a custom cell that, when tapped, animates similar to Snapchat's. I have gotten the animation to work, but as a scroll more (after tap), the last selected cell continues to animate as I tap around the screen. [Here's a video example](https://gph.is/g/aXYrOxn)

To get this animation, I am overriding the `isSelected` value in a custom cell class like so:

```
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            if isSelected {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                    self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.95, y: 0.95)
                }, completion: { _ in
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
                    }, completion: nil)
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help me figure out why the last selected cell continues to animate even after the correct animation is completed.

Comment: maybe you should change isSelected to false in completion block?

Comment: I just tried that in both completion blocks. No luck.

Comment: Hi, take a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45664054/9048325

Comment: @ВладиславШматок that did it!. Using `touchesBegan` and my own animate() func worked.